# strange horizontal scroll

Tags: css, scroll

I have a strange horizontal scroll, strange because I have a 100% width container.
Take a look at this [link](http://www.outboxvision.com/accordion/) to see what I'm talking about

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the `float` and `width` from the triggers.

Your elements have `width: 100%`, which causes them to occupy the entire width of the page.
You're adding a border and padding to them, which adds to that width and makes them bigger than the page.

Answer (score 0):

It's problematic to use `width` and `padding` at the same element.

Try to remove the `width` and additionally remove the `float` property from your `h2.trigger` class.

Comment: I wouldn't say it's "problematic" - you just have to make sure to account for it.

Comment: yes, but I'm trying to avoid it, since IE didn't render width+padding correctly.